# Импорт данных из листа другой таблицы Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть одна общая таблица, в которую я хочу передавать данные из многих других таблиц.

Основная таблица имеет листы по названию месяца и года, например "май 2019".
Вспомогательные таблицы имеют соответствующие листы.

Сейчас задача состоит в том, что я хочу передавать в формулу `IMPORTRANGE` в виде второго параметра (который отвечает за диапазон), переменную, которая будет содержать название листа, на котором формула `IMPORTRANGE` инициируется, чтобы автоматом подтягивать необходимый лист со вспомогательных таблиц.

Я пробовал передавать во второй параметр пользовательскую функцию, которую я создал:

```
function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
}
```

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.....";"sheetName()!B10")
```

Но выдает ошибку.

Подскажите, можно ли вообще такое реализовать каким-то образом? Или нужно пойти по какому-то другому пути? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать оператор `&`, который выполняет конкатенацию двух строк: имени листа, возвращенной функцией `sheetName()` и строки `!B10`

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://.."; sheetName() & "!B10")
```